# Display the largest element in each column in a 2D-array using pointers and function in C

Tags: c

Write a program to read matrix A that has a size of B x K and display **the largest element** in each column. Use **pointers** to access elements in an array.

**Note:** I need to use functions to solve this problem.

**Input**

```
4 4

1 3 2 1    
8 4 3 2    
1 2 3 4    
9 8 7 6
```

**Output**

```
9 8 7 6
```

Here is what I've been trying so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void MAX(int *ptr, int b, int k)
{
    int i, j, y;
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        y = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
        {
            if (y < *ptr)
            {
                y = *ptr;
            }
            ptr++;
        }
        printf("%d ", y);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int b, k;
    scanf("%d %d", &b, &k);
    int arr[b][k];

    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    MAX(&arr[0][0], b, k);
    return 0;
}
```

From what I've been trying so far, I don't get the output that matches the question. I've been looking for what's wrong, but I still didn't find it. So, could someone tell me what do I miss?

Comment: Think about how many times you are using `ptr++`. Also think about the order in which you are traversing the array.

Comment: That's a great opportunity to learn how to use your debugger. Depending on which debugger you have learning the basics will take you from 10 minutes to maybe an hour or so. Or at least you can put some `printf` at strategic places in your code so you can see what's going on.

Comment: I concur with Eric.  You're using `ptr++` too many times.  You should only need the `ptr++` outside the `if`.

Comment: Hint: your `MAX` function should have this prototype: `MAX(int ptr[b][k], int b, int k)`. Then you don't need pointer notation at all and it's going to be much easier. BTW: don't call your function `MAX` in all caps. Call it `Max` or `max`,  All caps identifiers are normally used for macros in C.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Not using pointer notation violates the assignment instructions to use pointer notation. The purpose of the assignment is to train the student in understanding pointer notation, regardless of its practicality in this case, the same way that instructing athletes to lift weights trains their muscles regardless of its practicality in raising masses to greater heights. You would not tell them to use machines to lift the weights because that would not train their muscles as desired, so do not tell students to use array notation because that does not train their brains as desired.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You would need to change the order of the parameters so that `b` and `k` are defined before `ptr`.

Comment: I have fixed the ptr++ section. But, I still don't get the output that matches the question.

The output I get is 3 8 4 9

Based on the output obtained, it looks like the loop is scanning from row to column. But, I've set up the loop to scan from the column first (for j = 0 and then for i = 0). Why does that happen?

Comment: @Jonathan Because `ptr++` is progressing linearly through the stored values, which are stored in row-major order.

Comment: You could change `ptr++` to `ptr += k;` to advance to the same column on the next row. But then after finishing a column you would need to reset `ptr` to the next column on the first row, e.g. `ptr = ptr - b * k + 1;`. But you may find it easier to use two pointers, especially as `ptr += k;` is illegal on the last row when `i == b - 1` and `k > 1`.